# Filter dataset using values from another dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, filter, dataset

I have dataset1 in which one of the column is clientid. I would like to filter it based on the clientids returned from a table valued sql function.
(I guess i can call the sql function from c# code and store result in dataset2. The sql function returns a column of cilentids).

I want the resultant dataset to have only those rows whose client id is contained in the dataset2.

Please help!

Comment: a dataset contains multiple datatables which contains multiple rows. I suppose you mean datatable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to Dataset to get the rows. This example gets the rows from the datable with id's 2 and 4.

```
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("value");
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "test1");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "test2");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "test3");
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "test4");
        int[] idfilter = new[] { 2, 4 };
        var filteredrows = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(f => idfilter.Contains(f.Field<int>("id")));
        foreach (var row in filteredrows)
            Console.WriteLine(row["id"]);
        Console.ReadLine();
```